# Classification based on order of feature occurence

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I have inputs coming from source in order. When the inputs match particular order it's classified into particular group. Based on this i had build my training file as below.

```
LABEL FEATURE1,FEATURE2,FEATURE3,FEATURE4
CLASS_A INPUT_A,INPUT_B,INPUT_C,INPUT_D
CLASS_A INPUT_A,INPUT_B,INPUT_C,INPUT_D
CLASS_A INPUT_A,INPUT_B,INPUT_C,INPUT_D
CLASS_A INPUT_A,INPUT_B,INPUT_C,INPUT_D
CLASS_B INPUT_C,INPUT_D,,
CLASS_B INPUT_C,INPUT_D,,
CLASS_B INPUT_C,INPUT_D,,
CLASS_C INPUT_A,INPUT_B,INPUT_D,
CLASS_C INPUT_A,INPUT_B,INPUT_D,
CLASS_C INPUT_A,INPUT_B,INPUT_D,
CLASS_C INPUT_A,INPUT_B,INPUT_D,
CLASS_C INPUT_A,INPUT_B,INPUT_D,
CLASS_D INPUT_E,INPUT_F,,
CLASS_D INPUT_E,INPUT_F,,
CLASS_D INPUT_E,INPUT_F,,
CLASS_D INPUT_E,INPUT_F,,
```

I am trying to use decision tree for doing the classification, but the problem its not taking order into consideration while building the model. Is Decision Tree right way to approach the problem, where the order of features is important for doing classification rather than the weight of each feature or is there better algorithms/approaches available for solving these kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Decision tree is *great* for this, but it appears that your chosen algorithm doesn't take order into account when it processes input.  If you're using pre-packaged algorithms, you might find it easier to edit your input file and tag each feature with its order: treat the order as a feature value.  For instance, your inputs might look like this:

```
CLASS_A 1 2 3 4 0 0
CLASS_B 0 0 1 2 0 0
CLASS_C 1 2 0 3 0 0
CLASS_D 0 0 0 0 1 2
```

This would allow you to choose from a variety of training algorithms: Decision Tree, Naive Bayes, SVM, even k-means clustering.